# Override updateShouldNotify in Flutter TickerMode?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to override `updateShouldNotify` in `TickerMode` (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TickerMode-class.html). It is listed as a method there but when I click into the code it doesn't actually have that method.

I do:

```
class MyTickerMode extends TickerMode {
  const MyTickerMode(
      {Key key, @required bool enabled, Widget child})
      : super(key: key, enabled: enabled, child: child);

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(TickerMode oldWidget) => false;
}
```

This returns the error `The method doesn't override an inherited method. #override_on_non_overriding_member`.

Why?
I also tried `updateShouldNotify(covariant TickerMode oldWidget)` and `updateShouldNotify(_)`.

Answer (score 0):

There are no `updateShouldNotify()` method in `TickerMode`. You need override this method when your class extend `InheritedWidget`. You can see it's overrides in `_EffectiveTickerMode` in `ticker_provider` file.

Finally, `The method doesn't override an inherited method` error occurs when you try to override method which are not exist in extendable class.